# Create a Sequence of case class objects from a Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

How do I iterate through Spark DataFrame rows and add them to a Sequence of case class objects?

DF1:

```
val someDF = Seq(
  ("202003101750", "202003101700",122),
  ("202003101800", "202003101700",12),
  ("202003101750", "202003101700",42)
).toDF("number", "word","value")
```

Case Class:

```
case class ValuePerNumber(num:String, wrd:String, defaultID:Int, size: Long=0) {}
```

Expected Output:

```
Seq(ValuePerNumber("202003101750", "202003101700",0, 122), ValuePerNumber("202003101800", "202003101700",0, 12), ValuePerNumber("202003101750", "202003101700",0, 42))
```

In each case I can have the defaultID as 0.
I am not sure how to approach and solve this problem and would really appreciate any solution / suggestion!

I have tried the following:

```
val x = someDF.as[ValuePerNumber].collect()
```

I get the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`num`' given input columns: [number, word, value];
```

EDIT: Kindly upvote if the question/solution helped you in anyway, that in turn will help me in this forum.

Comment: If you want to get a seq of classes you need to `collect()` the data to the driver. The alternative would be to create a `Dataset[ValuePerNumber]`.

Comment: @Shaido-ReinstateMonica I have edited my post with what I have tried and how I have used `collect` Doesnt seem to work here.

Comment: Your column names must match with those of the case class.

Comment: Rename your columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `Dataset[ValuePeerNumber]` and `collect` it as `Seq`

```
val someDF = Seq(
  ("202003101750", "202003101700",122),
  ("202003101800", "202003101700",12),
  ("202003101750", "202003101700",42)
).toDF("number", "word","value")

val result = someDF.map(r => ValuePerNumber(r.getAs[String](0), r.getAs[String](1), r.getAs[Int](2))).collect().toSeq
```

You can also add column in dataframe and edit the column name to match case class that you can directly do

```
val x = someDF.as[ValuePerNumber].collect()
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for!!! More accurately: 
```val result = someDF.map(r => ValuePerNumber(r.getAs[String](0), r.getAs[String](1), 0, r.getAs[Int](2))).collect().toSeq```

Answer (score 4):

Number of column count & names in both DataFrame & Case Class should match to use `as[ValuePerNumber]` on DataFrame directly without extracting values.

1. `size` is not available in DataFrame, so added using `withColumn`
2. Column names are not matched in both DF & Case class. Modified to match both DF & Case Class.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val someDF = Seq(("202003101750", "202003101700",122),("202003101800", "202003101700",12),("202003101750", "202003101700",42))
.toDF("number", "word","value")
.withColumn("size",lit(0)) // Added this to match your case class columns


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

someDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [number: string, word: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> case class ValuePerNumber(number:String, word:String, value:Int, size: Long=0) // Modified column names to match your dataframe column names.
defined class ValuePerNumber

scala> someDF.as[ValuePerNumber].show(false)
+------------+------------+-----+----+
|number      |word        |value|size|
+------------+------------+-----+----+
|202003101750|202003101700|122  |0   |
|202003101800|202003101700|12   |0   |
|202003101750|202003101700|42   |0   |
+------------+------------+-----+----+


scala>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
val someDF = Seq(
  ("202003101750", "202003101700",122),
  ("202003101800", "202003101700",12),
  ("202003101750", "202003101700",42)
).toDF("number", "word","value")

case class ValuePerNumber(number:String, word:String, defaultID:Int, value: Long)

someDF.withColumn("defaultId", lit(0)).as[ValuePerNumber].collect.toSeq
```